Does spring @Retryable create a new connection or use the same connection with server
I have a Spring project wherein I am using @Retryable annotation on a method. The method calls an API and posts some json payload to it.
I have set maxAttempts as 4 and a retry delay of 20 ms using Backoff.
I am debugging an issue and hence trying to understand if @Retryable creates a new connection(a new thread) with the server where the API is hosted after the specified delay(20 ms in my case) or uses the same connection(same thread)

Your retry logic will execute on one thread. If you make an HTTP request from within your retry logic, it will open and close the connection on each execution. We can't answer whether that will create a new server thread without knowing what HTTP server is running, but I can say with 99.99% confidence that yes, each request will spawn a thread to handle it.

@lane.maxwell, putting it simply, as per the configuration I defined above, there will be 4 different threads - one for each retry? And if yes, does the previous thread lose and close the connection?

Yes, but keep in mind that those threads are very short-lived. On the client side, a single thread will run to handle the retry and backoff; on the server side, a thread will be spawned to handle each request (assuming that you aren't running some weird single-threaded server).

The @Retryable uses the RetryTemplate and that one has the logic like this:
        while (canRetry(retryPolicy, context) && !context.isExhaustedOnly()) {

            try {
                ...
                T result = retryCallback.doWithRetry(context);
                doOnSuccessInterceptors(retryCallback, context, result);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {

                ...

                if (canRetry(retryPolicy, context) && !context.isExhaustedOnly()) {
                    ...
                }

                ...
        }

So, all the retry attempts are happening on the same thread - the calling one.

Thanks Artem Bilan. The logic makes perfect sense. However, I am trying to link these 2(@Retryable and RetryTemplate). To me it appears to be 2 different ways of applying the retry logic. Can you help me with how @Retryable uses RetryTemplate? I am going through Retryable.java and not able to figure out how it uses RetryTemplate

The @EnableRetry imports for us a RetryConfiguration. That one scans beans for the @Retryable and applies on those methods an AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor with the RetryTemplate logic.
